# Result consisted of more than one row SQL=INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

While inserting first time it gives following error: "Result consisted of more than one row".  When i try to insert record second time it gives error with message duplicate entry.

```
 SQL=INSERT INTO `master_user` (`name`,`user_name`,`email`,`password`,`system_name_of_friend`,`system_no_of_friend`,`registered_from_site`,`registered_on`,`is_existing_user`) VALUES ('FirstName LastName','username','demo@mail.com','8c71eede42e38709e9e836021b0b9b9b','','','site','','1')
```

any one help will be appropriated and following is the table structure which will be get help to tracking this issue very easily and get the solution for this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `master_user` (
  `master_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `system_name_of_friend` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `system_no_of_friend` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `registered_from_ip` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_from_site` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_existing_user` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`master_user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ukMasterUser_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1293 ;
```

Comment: Please show us your full code!

Comment: Add the table structure also. Need to know which of the column is unique.

Comment: Check the table structure now and give me the updated query code please.

Comment: Is the INSERT statement part of a stored procedure?

Comment: No Mike, Its not an stored procedure it's simple insert query.

Comment: I get "Out of range value" warnings for columns "registered_on" and "is_existing_user". What version of MySQL?

Comment: MySQL server version: 5.5.40-36.1

Comment: I can't reproduce the error here with that version of MySQL.

Comment: I have changed the few words from column Which are conflicting and resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the few words from column Which are conflicting and resolved.